# There is a way to change the name of chrome tab in nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

Here where i work most of the people is used to work with multiples tabs of nifi-flows soo i wonder if there is a way to change that name like instead of "Nifi Flow" could be "Process Group Name" something like that.

Answer (score 0):

try this chrome-extension

[Tab Modifier](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-modifier/hcbgadmbdkiilgpifjgcakjehmafcjai)

use your **processGroupId** as your "URL Fragment"

e.g. https://MyNifiServer.com:8443/nifi/?processGroupId=fc81089b-axc3-3xdx-fxcc-6x426x0d6x4&componentIds=

you must use **"fc81089b-axc3-3xdx-fxcc-6x426x0d6x4"**

[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1eK0.png)